# Complicated join in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having an issue with a tricky ActiveRecord query.

I have three models, User, Task, and Response. A user submits responses to tasks. I'm using the has_many, through: pattern in ActiveRecord.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :responses
  has_many :responses

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :responses
  has_many :tasks, through: :responses

class Response < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task, optional: false
  belongs_to :user, optional: false
```

I'm trying to write a query that says, given a user_id, get all tasks where there is no Response from that User linked to it.

So if User 1 is querying, and he only has a Response to task 1, he should see all tasks except task 1.

Comment: As I see, `user` has `tasks` `through` `responses`. How can there be a `task` for which a user has no `response` but he is connected to it ? Or the user just does not have to be connected with that task at all ?

Comment: Could you provide the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a subquery to select all Task records that the User has Response to and they will be excluded from the main query. This will give you all Task records that the User (params[:user_id]) doesn't have Response to

```
Task.where.not(id: Response.select(:task_id).where(user_id: params[:user_id]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Task.where('user_id != (?)', User.find(user_id).responses)
```

or

```
Task.joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id != (?)', User.find(user_id))
```

Comment: The first will not work correctly as `!=` with a non-scalar list of `Response` is invalid and will raise a SQL level error because the query is essentially `SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks WHERE tasks.user_id !=(SELECT responses.* FROM responses WHERE user_id = [USER_ID_HERE])`

Comment: The second answer is the cleanest since it avoids the subquery. As engineersmnky pointed out, the first one will not run.

Comment: Actually, I've looked over this, and I'm not sure the second answer works. First, there's an error because it should simply be user id, not User.find(user_id) at the end for the comparison. Second, shouldn't it be a left_outer_join because we want to get tasks that don't have any responses as well? I tried doing that, but it's still not working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: My rewritten version. Hoping someone can weigh in on what's wrong with this

`Task.left_outer_joins(:responses).where('responses.user_id != (?)', user_id)`

Comment: I believe the error is coming from responses.user_id being blank on tasks that have no responses and not being returned because the inverse (equals instead of not equals) works.

Comment: I am not sure that simple join approach will solve your problem. The thing is if you have many responses to Task=1, where one belongs to User=1 but the rest of the responses are coming from other users, with join you will only filter the one match that is for User=1, but still, Task=1 will be returned because of the other responses for Task=1.